# Move multiple files from filename list to a new folder

Tags: linux, find, cat

I have a list of filename in list.txt, which have 'abc1.png, abc2.png, abc3.png....'.

However, I don't know the directories where the files are.

I want to find all files in the txt file, and move them to a new folder.

Comment: It would be rather difficult to do in one shell command since AFAIK you can't pipe cat to find or locate, so I'd reccomend  using `find / -name a.png` to locate the directory, then running `cd DIRECTORY; mv $(cat list.txt) ~/` or you could write a more complicated shell script to loop through line by line, but that might cost more time than it saves.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [read each filename line-by-line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), then try to `find` it using the `name` option, and finally `mv` it to the target:

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    find /somewhere -type f -name "$filename" -exec mv -- {} /somewhere/else/ \;
done < file.txt
```

The `{}` will be replaced with the found file path.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file names do not contain ", " or newlines and every file exists in list.txt only once. You also naturally have to change newdirectory to directory you want. If any file in list.txt is missing, the file is not copied (and no info given).

```
sed -s "s/, /\\n/g" list.txt | xargs -IFILE -n1 find -name FILE -exec mv {} newdirectory \;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is easy with some bash :

first find your files with find and redirect the ouptut in another file :

> for arg in $(cat list.txt); do find / -name $arg -print >> files_with_path.txt; done

then mv the files :

> for arg in $(cat files_with_path.txt); do mv $arg /your/dest/folder; done

Comment: Please read: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) – your command will fail in certain situations, notably when files (or found paths) contain whitespace.

Comment: Search for every single file through entire filesystem??